# addToSet with multiple condition in aggregation mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have **document** like this:

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc3c093c05bd833c4258e25"),
    "subscriber_id" : 4504,
    "user_country" : "India",
    "event" : "eventA"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc3c093c05bd833c4258e25"),
    "subscriber_id" : 4504,
    "user_country" : "India",
    "event" : "eventB"
  }
```

From below **query** I get:

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
   { 
      $project:{ 
         _id:1,
         user_country:1,
         subscriber_id:1,
         event:1
      }
   },
   { 
      $group:{ 
         "_id":{ 
            "subscriber_id":"$subscriber_id",
            "eventA":{ 
               $cond:{ 
                  "if":{ 
                     "$and":[ 
                        { 
                           "$eq":[ 
                              "$event",
                              "eventA"
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  then:1,
                  else:0
               }
            },
            "eventB":{ 
               $cond:{ 
                  "if":{ 
                     "$and":[ 
                        { 
                           "$eq":[ 
                              "$event",
                              "eventB"
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  then:1,
                  else:0
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { 
      $group:{ 
         "_id":{ 
            "subscriber_id":"$_id.subscriber_id"
         },
         "event_details":{ 
            $push:{ 
               "eventA":"$_id.eventA",
               "eventB":"$_id.eventB"
            }
         }
      }
   }
);
```

**Output:**

```
{ 
   "_id":{ 
      "subscriber_id":4504
   },
   "event_details":[ 
      { 
         "eventA":0,
         "eventB":0
      },
      { 
         "eventA":1,
         "eventB":0
      },
      { 
         "eventA":0,
         "eventB":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want for each row whatever *event* has `1` value should be push into array so my next step output should be like this

```
{ 
   "_id":{ 
      "subscriber_id":4504
   },
   "event_details":[ 
      "eventA",
      "eventB"
   ]
}
```

Here `eventA` and `eventB` both has value `1`, so both will pushed to array.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? You just have to have one group stage to achieve what you need :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$subscriber_id",
      event_details: {
        $addToSet: "$event"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Will output :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 4504,
    "event_details": [
      "eventB",
      "eventA"
    ]
  }
]
```